# How can I use regex to capture this specfic set of ages?

Tags: regex

I have a set of age data, like below;

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,12
11,13,15
7,8,12
12,15
14,16,17
15,6
13,11,10,2
```

And so on...  I am trying to use Regex in to target a 'mixed' range of childrens ages.  The logic requires at least a combination of 2 childen (so requires one of the lines with a comma), with at least one aged under 10 (min is 1), and at least one aged equal or greater to 10 (max 17).

My expected results from the above would be to return these lines below, and nothing else;

```
2,12
7,8,12
15,6
13,11,10,2
```

Any advice would be appreciated on how to resolve?  Thanks in advance, I am continuing to try to correct.

Comment: which language is this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739633/regex-standards-across-languages

Comment: This is [for GA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229345/regular-expression-not-working-in-google-analytics-possibly-due-to-positive-loo), and it won't work there. RE2 does not support lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to meet your requirements:

```
^(?=.*\b[1-9]\b)(?=.*\b1[0-7]\b)[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN2jB0/6)

- There are 2 lookaheads to assert 2 numbers one between `1-9` and another between `10-17`
- `([1-9])` matches a number that should be between `1` and `9`
- `1[0-7]` matches a number that should be between `10` and `17`
- `[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)+` in the regex is for matching 1 or more comma separated numbers in the middle.

Comment: hi @anubhava unfortunately this won't capture if the numbers are the other way around.  i.e. 15,2.  The dataset is much larger and just reflects that captured in Google Analytics.  I need it to look regardless of the order.  I have updated the question and hope it helps explain further the challenge.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: it's perfect, I just made one tweak as the first group has to be aged 9 or below, so I removed the 'or 10' ;

    ^(?=.*\b(?:[1-9])\b)(?=.*\b1[0-7]\b)[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)+$

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @anubhava, would you know why this wouldn't work in Google Analytics, or should I open a new question?  It seems perfect, but Google Analytics says it's an invalid regular expression (I think that means it's too advanced for Google :) )

Comment: Does Google Analytics support lookahead? If not then pls go ahead and open a question linking to this one

Comment: done - thank you for the help! [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229345/regular-expression-not-working-in-google-analytics-possibly-due-to-positive-loo)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
\b\d,1[0-7]\b
```

provided the ages always are sorted (youngest to oldest).

If the age of 0 isn't allowed, change to

```
\b[1-9],1[0-7]\b
```

It checks for a single digit followed by a comma and one followed by a single digit in the range 0-7.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sK3gA4/2).

Comment: You asked a new question, but... Did you even try this one? There's no look-ahead, and I doubt you'll find a simpler one.

Comment: Hi @ClasG - I did try this, and it would be much better as the expression is nice and simple, but unfortunately the data isn't always sorted from youngest to oldest, i.e. one of my example lines was 15,6 and this regex doesn't capture that.  I ended up with a crazy solution, that works, from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229345/regular-expression-not-working-in-google-analytics-possibly-due-to-positive-loo?noredirect=1#comment63888417_38229345)

Comment: OK, I get it. The simple solution then, if you can't handle look-arounds, is to add an alternation that checks it the otherway around - `\b(?:\d,1[0-7]|1[0-7],\d)\b` - [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sK3gA4/3)