# Regular Expression not working in Google Analytics, possibly due to Positive Lookahead?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a regular expression here which works perfectly in Regex101 ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN2jB0/6)). *anubhava* provided this solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222893/how-can-i-use-regex-to-capture-this-specfic-set-of-ages/38227784?noredirect=1#comment63880355_38227784).

```
/^(?=.*\b[1-9]\b)(?=.*\b1[0-7]\b)[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)+$/gm
```

However, when I try to use it in Google Analytics, I get this warning - "**Invalid regular expression**. Your data request includes an invalid regular expression."

Do you know how I can get the same results, but satisfy Google Analytics security requirements, which seem to be disallowing lookaheads?

Comment: seems like GA do not supports lookarounds..

Comment: Could you do a quick test for `^(([0-9]+,)*[0-7],([0-9]+,)*[1-9][0-9](,|$))|(([0-9]+,)*[1-9][0-9],([0-9]+,)*[0-7](,|$))` in google analytics? It assumes, that your data is always in the given format with lines only consisting of commas and numbers

Comment: also invalid unfortunately @SebastianProske

Comment: looks like they are pretty restrictive https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en

Comment: Yeah they are.

This one works for me, targeting permutations where ages are less than 10 throughout the group - `^(?:[^\n\d]*\b[1-9]\b[^\n\d]*)+$`

What I need this one to do is target any permutation where there is at least 2 in a group, with at least one aged less than 10, and at least one aged 10 or over.

Comment: @PhilBarnes tested it here: http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester - though not sure, if this tool actually works

Comment: How do you get the data to GA? I have given up on GA regex and use PHP to do the calculations/filtering/or whatever and then pass a custom dimension to GA that I can read.

Comment: @Andreas that comment is a question in its own right and does not belong as a comment

Comment: @WillBarnwell what?? You mean I should post a question on SO to ask OP in this thread how he gathers the data?

Comment: @Andreas my apologies, I previously misread your question, I thought you were asking advice, after rereading I felt silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((^|,)([0-9]|(1[0-7])))*((((^|,)[0-9](,[0-9]|(1[0-7]))*(,1[0-7])))|(((^|,)1[0-7]((,[0-9]|(1[0-7])))*(,[0-9]))))(,([0-9]|(1[0-7])))*$
```

Thanks to [GA's extremely limited regex language](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en), this is a pretty inefficient and gross regex, but it matches your use cases.

https://regex101.com/r/oN2jB0/8

Comment: A massive thanks @Will_Barnwell - would never have got to this point without you.  This did the job perfectly, and got around Google Analytic's crazy tight rules!