# Differences between PCRE and extended

Tags: regex, grep, notepad++, pcre

I had the following examples working with extended `grep` and with `sed`:

```
grep -E --color '^L' input.txt
grep -E --color 'L$' input.txt

grep -E --color '02-?2' input.txt
grep -E --color '2+' input.txt
grep -E --color '22+' input.txt
grep -E --color '222?' input.txt
grep -E --color 'AAA*' input.txt
grep -E --color 'A{3}' input.txt
grep -E --color 'A{2,}' input.txt
grep -E --color 'A{2,3}' input.txt

grep -E --color '(^Re|him|AL$)' input.txt
grep -E --color '^(Re|him|AL)' input.txt
grep -E --color '(Re|him|AL)$' input.txt

grep -E --color '[1-9]{8,}' input.txt
grep -E --color '[12390]{8,}' input.txt
grep -E --color '0[1-9]-[^57]{7,}' input.txt
grep -E --color '0.-[0-9]+' input.txt
grep -E --color '0.-[0-9z]+' input.txt

grep -E --color 'a[[:space:]]+0' input.txt
grep -E --color '[^[:digit:][:space:]]{5,}' input.txt

sed -E 's/^[[:alpha:]]+/Name/g' input.txt
sed -E 's/^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]*(0.)/Name: \1\tPhone: \2/g' input.txt
```

The input file is:

```
Reuven  02-2342312  AAAABB
Shimon  08-8156831  AACDEF
Levi    03-639z387  UYGnAL
Yehuda  022221938   UYGnBL
The period. Another period.
```

I tried the same searches and substitutions in `nodepad++` expecting that at least some of them would fail, since [`nodepad++` uses the PCRE syntax](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions). However all of them worked.

I tried to google for the differences between the two syntaxes (Extended and PCRE), but did not find anything. What are they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx standards across languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739633/regex-standards-across-languages)

Comment: PCRE syntax could be called a superset of ERE. However, there may be some engine  peculiarities that produce different results compared to PCRE because those utilities follow POSIX. Even BRE syntax doesn't lead to syntactic error in PCRE but it definitely produces different results in some cases.